# Installing/enabling PHP Pecl Intl extension on a default Mac OS X Leopard bundled PHP configuration

Tags: php, macos, pecl, icu, intl

How can I install or enable the PHP Pecl Intl extension in my PHP environment?

I've got a stock PHP configuration that came bundled with Mac OS X Snow Leopard.
Installing libicu from source and than `$pecl install intl` results in the following error:

```
 /private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_class.c:92: error: duplicate 'static'
 /private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_class.c:96: error: duplicate 'static'
 /private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_class.c:101: error: duplicate 'static'
 /private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_class.c:107: error: duplicate 'static'
 make: *** [collator/collator_class.lo] Error 1
 ERROR: `make' failed
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: do you want to uninstall first before install?

Comment: If you mean uninstall my complete PHP environment, than I'd rather not. I'm in the middle of a project that is far to big to take the risk of having to install PHP.

Comment: @ajreal, That's not possible. I don't have a PECL install for Intl. Just to be sure I tried `pecl uninstall intl` but it told me that was not possible since it's not installed to begin with. The problem seems to be rooted in the fact that the source is bundled with my PHP distribution but that it's not enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>For the time being I've recompiled my PHP installation. I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/03b9175bdb33ab2ce129) with my configure string which I'll keep updating.</del>

## update

[liip](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) have created a nice binary that circumvents all these troubles. It is based on the original [entropy.ch](http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/php/) binary, I recomend using it for PHP development on a Mac.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I did in OSX 10.9 Mavericks:

1. Install some dependencies with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

   ```
   $ brew install autoconf
   $ brew install icu4s
   $ brew link --force icu4s
   ```
2. Install and verify Pear/PECL (instructions from http://techtastico.com/post/como-instalar-pear-y-pecl-en-os-x-mavericks/):

   ```
   $ curl -O http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
   $ sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
     [ Select 1 and enter /usr/local/pear ]
     [ Select 4 and enter /usr/local/bin ]
     [ Press return ]
   $ pear version
   ```
3. Install PECL intl:

   ```
   $ sudo pecl install intl
   $ sudo cp /private/etc/php.ini{.default,}
   $ sudo chmod 644 /private/etc/php.ini
   $ echo extension=intl.so >> /private/etc/php.ini
   ```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me to install the intl extension on mavericks. I skipped the pear/pecl install and I brew installed icu4c instead. It fixed a composer dependency issue I was having: "requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing"

Comment: if you got error that missing `<php.h>` please enter this commend in Yosemite or El Capitan `xcode-select –-install`

Comment: Thats great thanks, but it should be `brew install icu4c`

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never, but if you are like me and installed PHP directly from php.net (instead of using something like Homebrew or Port, then you can simply follow the following link to install Pear and PECL:

http://akrabat.com/php/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-10-7-lion/

It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

on my Mac I installed a php version with pear using brew. This solved all my issues as the default osX php didn't work for me after trying many different ways. You can try without installing php/pear if you have already done so.

You need Homebrew http://brew.sh/

Install PHP

`brew install php56 --with-pear` or `brew install php56 pear`

Install autoconf

`brew install autoconf`

Install icu4c

`brew install icu4c`

Creates the symlinks

`brew link --force icu4c`

Install intl with (pearl) pecl

`sudo pecl install intl`

Homebrew should enable intl and symlink all the right versions to their respective commands.